# Elasticsearch Nest Client MatchPhrasePrefix

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am having a weird thing happening, which I can not explain, maybe someone can shed some light into this.

I use C# Nest Client.  I query an index of customers.  When I search for:

Rad

I get 4 results:
Radowitch
Radinost
Radinski
Radastowitz

When I query for:
Radt

I get 2 results:
Radtko
Radtonski

Now why are the 2 results not part of the result list of the Rad Query?  And how can I query for Rad and get all 6 matching results?

Sorry I am fairly new to elastic search and also the Nest Library.

IndexMapping:

```
{
    "crm-customers": {
        "mappings": {
            "customer": {
                "properties": {
                    "adresse": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ort": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "postleitzahl": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "strasse": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "anonymized": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "anrede": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "bearbeiterId": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "bearbeiterRatenkreditId": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "bearbeiterVersicherungId": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "createdAt": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "deleted": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "email": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "emailGeschaeftlich": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "familienstand": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "faxPrivat": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "fullname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "geburtstag": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "informationspflichtErfolgtAm": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "isEmail1Valid": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "isEmail2Valid": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "kundeSeit": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "leadKategorie": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "leadKategorieManuelleNeuanlage": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "modifiedAt": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "monatlichesEinkommen": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "nachname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "personId": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "telefonGeschaeftlich": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "telefonMobilPrivat": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "telefonPrivat": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "titel": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "vorname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query Code Block:

```cs
            query = query.ToLower();
            var asyncResponse = await this._client.SearchAsync<Customer>(s => s
                .From((page - 1) * pageSize)
                .Size(pageSize)
                .Index(_index)
                .Sort(ss => ss
                    .Descending(SortSpecialField.Score)
                )
                .Query(q =>
                    (q.MatchPhrasePrefix(c =>
                        c.Field(p => p.Fullname)
                        .Boost(3)
                        .Query(query)
                    ) ||
                    q.MultiMatch(c =>
                        c.Fields(f => f
                            .Field(p => p.Fullname)
                            .Field(p => p.Email)
                            .Field(p => p.EmailGeschaeftlich)
                            .Field(p => p.Adresse.Strasse)
                            .Field(p => p.Adresse.Ort)
                        ).Query(query)
                    )) &&
                    (
                        q.Terms(c => c
                            .Field(p => p.BearbeiterId)
                            .Terms(bearbeiterIds)
                        ) ||
                        q.Terms(c => c
                            .Field(p => p.BearbeiterRatenkreditId)
                            .Terms(bearbeiterIds)
                        ) ||
                        q.Terms(c => c
                            .Field(p => p.BearbeiterVersicherungId)
                            .Terms(bearbeiterIds)
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
            return asyncResponse;
```

Comment: Could you share your index mapping? You can get it with `GET localhost:9200/indexname/_mapping`.

Comment: and also if you could include search requests you tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean with search requests exactly?

Comment: How do you search for "Rad"? Which query type do you use?

Comment: I use the Nest Library with .Query(q => q.MatchPhrasePrefix( c => c.Field(p => p.Fullname).Boost(3).Query("Rad"))

Comment: could you post whole code block with the query?

Comment: Added the Query Code Block